# for loop make the output side by side jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  success: function(data) {
  var tr;
  if (data.error === true) {
    alert(data.message);
  }

  $("#Names").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td id='groupnumber'>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id='groupname'>" + data[i].groupname + "</td>");
    var Names = data[i].Names;
    for (var q = 0; q < Names.length; q++) {
      tr.append("<td id='Names'>" + Names[q].firstname + " " + Names[q].lastname + "</td>"); //group members
    }
    tr.append("<td id='project'>" + data[i].project + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id='adviser'>" + data[i].adviser + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id='prof'>" + data[i].prof + "</td>");
    $("#Names").append(tr);
  }
},
```

I have the code above to append to my table it works ok but i want to make it better i want to ask idea on how to make it in way that my result for names with be outputted in one `td`. Currently its output visual representation is like this

`|other td|John Smith|Agent Smith|Neo matrix|other td|`

`Fyi` I have other append before and after the snippet ` paste above.

What i want it to look like is something like this

`|other td|John Smith(, or / )Agent Smith(, or / )Neo Matrix|other td|`

To sum it all all i want tot happened is when the names are generated i want all names to share only one `td`

`Update`

Sample data

```
[{
    "groupid": "1",
    "groupname": "group 1",
    "project": "Project 1",
    "adviser": "Mr. Smith",
    "prof": "Prof X",
    "Names": [{
        "firstname": "Scott",
        "lastname": "Summers"
    }]
}, {
    "groupid": "2",
    "groupname": "group 2",
    "project": "Project 2",
    "adviser": "Mr. Anderson",
    "prof": "Magneto",
    "Names": [{
        "firstname": "Magneto",
        "lastname": "Poles"
    }]
}, {
    "groupid": "3",
    "groupname": "group 3",
    "project": "Project 3",
    "adviser": "Mr. Fury",
    "prof": "Magneto",
    "Names": [{
        "firstname": "Tony",
        "lastname": "Stark"
    }, {
        "firstname": "Natasha",
        "lastname": "romanoff"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: what is tr. in your script?

Comment: `var tr;` `tr = $('<tr/>');` then i have `$("#Names").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();` this is at the beginning of the for loop then i have `$("#Names").append(tr);` before ending the for loop

Comment: Can include `html` `data` array at OP ?

Comment: @guest271314 the data is from ajax data success so i cant include it i can out the entire code of success if you want i just though it is not relevant let me change it give me a minute

Comment: `Names` property not appear at "Sample data" ?

Comment: [Something like this should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/a5kqLs5n/)

Comment: @Joonas actually it could work i didnt think of that let me try it and il get back on you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var Names = data[i].Names;
var td = $("<td id='Names' />");
for (var q = 0; q < Names.length; q++) {
  td.append(Names[q].firstname + " " + Names[q].lastname + ", ");  
}
tr.append(td);
$("#Names").append(tr);
```

Comment: It still skip one  td because it still counted that td as 2 so the output is `|sometd|blnk td where the first should be|firstvalue/secondvalue|some td|`

Comment: Please correct your answer. `td.append`, you pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var tr = [];
$.map(data, function(value, key) {
  tr.push(
    $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='groupnumber'>" + value.groupid + "</td>"
     })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='groupname'>" + value.groupname + "</td>"
    })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='Names'>" 
               + $.map(value.Names, function(name, i) {
                     return name.firstname + " " + name.lastname
                 }).join(", ") 
               + "</td>"
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='project'>" + value.project + "</td>",
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='adviser'>" + value.adviser + "</td>"
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='prof'>" + value.prof + "</td>"
      })[0]
  );
});

$("#Names").append(tr);
```

---

```js
var data = [{
  "groupid": "1",
  "groupname": "group 1",
  "project": "Project 1",
  "adviser": "Mr. Smith",
  "prof": "Prof X",
  "Names": [{
    "firstname": "Scott",
    "lastname": "Summers"
  }]
}, {
  "groupid": "2",
  "groupname": "group 2",
  "project": "Project 2",
  "adviser": "Mr. Anderson",
  "prof": "Magneto",
  "Names": [{
    "firstname": "Magneto",
    "lastname": "Poles"
  }]
}, {
  "groupid": "3",
  "groupname": "group 3",
  "project": "Project 3",
  "adviser": "Mr. Fury",
  "prof": "Magneto",
  "Names": [{
    "firstname": "Tony",
    "lastname": "Stark"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Natasha",
    "lastname": "romanoff"
  }]
}];

var tr = [];
$.map(data, function(value, key) {
  tr.push(
    $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='groupnumber'>" + value.groupid + "</td>"
     })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='groupname'>" + value.groupname + "</td>"
    })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='Names'>" 
               + $.map(value.Names, function(name, i) {
                     return name.firstname + " " + name.lastname
                 }).join(", ") 
               + "</td>"
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='project'>" + value.project + "</td>",
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='adviser'>" + value.adviser + "</td>"
      })[0]
    , $("<tr />", {
        "html":"<td id='prof'>" + value.prof + "</td>"
      })[0]
  );
});

$("#Names").append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody id="Names">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i didnt do it who ever did it should explain not me